# Java mapping json to two objects

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jersey, jpa-2.1

I use Jersey to provide REST API.
I wrote controller, which map request to entity:

```
@POST
@Path("register")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response UserRegistration(User UserData)
{


}
```

It works fine for simple json like:

```
{
"email":"email@email.pl",
"name":"Name",
"surname":"surname"
}
```

and entity:

```
    public class User {

    public User() {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id",unique = true)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String email;

    //getters

    // setters
}
```

How can I map JSON array like:

```
{
"email":"email@email.pl",
"name":"Name",
"surname":"surname"
"reqData":{
    "ip":44.44.44.44}
}
```

To two entites?
First entity: user (shown above) and entity reqData:

```
public class RegistrationData {

    public RegistrationData(){};

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "ip")
    private int ip;
```

I have of course One to One relationship, but it is not important here(I think).
I hope my question is understandable.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

I had to modify my json request and make additional class.

It works very well for me.
I thought that framewrok will do it for me :<

New JSON:

```
{
   "user":{
      "email":"email@email.com",
      "name":"xxxx",
      "surname":"fffff"
   },
   "reqData":{
      "ip":"1223123"
   }
}
```

Mapping: (will return "email@email.com")

```
    @POST
    @Path("test")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String Test(Test Testclass)
    {
        return Testclass.getUser().getEmail();
    }
}
```

and class

```
public class Testclass {

    public Testclass(){};

    // getters 

    //setters
    private User user;

    private RegistrationData reqData;
}
```